# Passing variable into a modal through spacebars

Tags: meteor, spacebars

Is there a way without going to JavaScript that Spacebars can pass a variable to a modal?

For example, when I try:

```
<button type="button" id="genbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#entryModal">Pass</button>
{{> newentry var=item}}
```

It does not work inside the modal:

```
<template name="newentry">
 {{#with var}}It displays here!{{/with}}
<div id="entryModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
 {{#with var}}Does not display here!{{/with}}
```

(Rest of modal works just fine)

I can't figure out why the variable can get into the template, but not past the modal.  Otherwise the modal's non-var related functions work just fine.  Why does this interrupt?  Can it be overcome?  If so, how?

Note: If this cannot work without going to the JavaScript, I can do it, but it feels like the wrong solution to this problem.

Comment: Are you sure that item is defined? Can you try another name than var? It might be a reserved word. BTW why don't you use an {{#if}} if you need to show just some text?

Comment: I'm not using 'var', that is an example.  The variable I pass to the template works just fine expect within the modal class.  As for using #if vs using #when, I get the exact same behavior of working outside of the div but not inside.

Answer (score 0):

I had the slimier Issue recently so I just share my working example. I am using the below code and it's work perfectly.

```
{{>userInfo userId=customer._id userType='Customer'}}
```

then in userInfo template i got the userType as:

```
<div class="panel panel-{{currentColor ../userType}} user-info">
```

Please note the `../` before userType. and I am also using userId in js as:

```
Template.currentData().userId
```

so that can be used in any way like am doing as a helper

```
relatedUser: function(){
        return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Template.currentData().userId})
}
```

hope my examples can help :)

**Update**

make a helper in newentry Template as :

```
myReactiveHelper: function(){
    return Template.currentData().var
}
```

and then in your template bind that helper instead of `var` as :

```
{{#with myReactiveHelper}}Does not display here!{{/with}}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be doing anything for me.  Looks like I'm going to have to use JavaScript to get around my issue for now.   Just don't know why the modal class destroys my data context!

Comment: @CodeDragonDM change to`var` to any other name and consider the nested model layers. If you have model within child model you might use as `../../varname`

Comment: 'var' isn't the name I'm using, just an example.  Again with the proper variable name it's getting data to the template, just dies before going to the modal 'div'.  Using '../varname' or '../../varname' isn't working either.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better and simple to use `Jquery lightbox_me` plugin which wrap your modal into meteor templates.
For example.

```
$body = $('body')
UI.render Template.release_info, $body[0] //rendering template
$popup =  $body.find("#releases-info-popup-container") // modal Id
$popup.lightbox_me
  centered: true
  destroyOnClose: true
```

Template

```
<Template name="release_info">
   <div id="releases-info-popup-container">
   </div>
</Template>
```